# .htacces 301 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I created .htaccess file and I did configure redirects www to non-www, http to https and cutting .html from the end of urls.

Now I want to redirect 302 old pages to new one's.

Here I'm changing index to home page and it works:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=302,L]
```

Now I'm trying to change first old url to new one and it shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in web browser.

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/panele
RewriteRule (.*) /panele-podlogowe [R=302,L]
```

What should I do to find a problem? Is there infinite loop in code or something in apache config?

Here is whole .htaccess file:

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?panele$ /panele-podlogowe [R=302,L]

#redirect index to homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index
RewriteRule (.*) / [R,L]

#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R] 

#cutting .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The pattern `^/panele` of course matches on `/panele-podlogowe` as well. You need to anchor your pattern at the end as well, if you want it to match _only_ `/panele`.

Comment: Btw., you should not need a RewriteCond here to check the path, you can do that directly via the RewriteRule pattern. (You only have to keep in mind, that the path never starts with a leading / when this is configured in .htaccess, that will have been stripped off at this point already.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you tell me how can I anchor /panele-podlogowe?

Comment: `^` anchors a pattern at the beginning, `$` anchors it at the end.

Comment: "I did configure redirects www to non-www" - there are no www to non-www redirects in the code you've posted? Are you hosting multiple domains on this one account?

Answer (score 1):

Your "panele" rule is problematic.  It redirects:

- `http://example.com/panele` to
- `http://example.com/panele-podlogowe` to
- `http://example.com/panele-podlogowe` to
- `http://example.com/panele-podlogowe` to
- `http://example.com/panele-podlogowe` to
- `http://example.com/panele-podlogowe` to
- ...

It is an infinite self-redirect.

You can verify this with a redirect checking tool.  I usually use `curl` on the command line.

```sh
$ curl --head http://example.com/panele
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
...
Location: http://example.com/panele-podlogowe

$ curl --head http://example.com/panele-podlogowe
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
...
Location: http://example.com/panele-podlogowe
```

It seems likely that you want to redirect only the first URL.  You can do that by adding a `$` to the end of `panele` so that it isn't just a "starts-with" rule but rather an exact-match rule.    You can also move your condition into the rule itself.  I always make the first slash optional so that the rule can be used in either .htaccess or in Apache conf files.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?panele$ /panele-podlogowe [R=302,L]
```

I pasted your entire .htaccess file including this rule directly into my server and changed the `example.com` to my domain name.  I verified that it works fine using `curl`:

```sh
$ curl --head https://mysite.example/panele
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 17 May 2022 12:36:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://mysite.example/panele-podlogowe
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. Yes, I want to redirect /panele to /panele-podlogowe.
Now I'm testing my website with curl and it says that /panele is 301 pernamently moved to /panele so I changed 302 to 301.  Either 302 nor 301 is not working with your code.

Comment: This rule does not redirect to `/panele` so it must be something else doing that.  Do you have any other contents in your .htaccess?   If so, edit it into your question or try moving this redirect rule up to the top.

Comment: Redirects are on the top of .htaccess. I edited post and whole content is in original post.

Comment: I tested your .htaccess file with this rule on my own web server.   It seems to work fine for me. See the update I edited into my answer.

Comment: @TheMajlos "it says that /panele is 301 pernamently moved" - where did the 301 come from? Only 302 (temporary) redirects are used above (and in your question). Bear in mind that 301 (permanent) redirects are _cached_, so if you have previously experimented with 301s then you might be seeing an erroneously cached response.

Comment: @mrwhite the first comment on this answer says "changed 302 to 301" so it could have come from that.  It also says the testing is with `curl` which doesn't cache redirects the way that browsers do.  But your point is very valid if any testing is being done with browsers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "**so** I changed 302 to 301" - Although from the wording, that would seem to have been in response to seeing the report that "/panele is 301 pernamently moved to..."?